# Visual Studio Output using DTE on Powershell?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2015, automation

I was wondering if there is a way to access the Output Window Panes using Powershell Script through the DTE interface?

I am trying to implement the following but can't any help would be highly appreciated:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.outputwindow.outputwindowpanes.aspx

P.S. The project that we are trying to compile is not MSBuild compatible, so running the MSBuild utility and funneling the output to a file does not work.

Comment: Exactly what have you tried?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen So I have tried in a very naive way the following: $panes = $dte.ToolWindows.OutputWindow.OutputWindowPanes, but it seems like this is pointing to a NULL and hence I am suspecting that I am over-simplifying this. But if I have access to the OutputWindowPanes I can iterate through, and find the ones that I am interested in and fetch the text from them! Any suggestions?